# split multiple selections into separate records in a Django model

Tags: python, django

I have two django models connected by a foreign key. The second model has a CharField that allows for multiple selections. Is there a way upon saving that I can create a record for each selection, instead of having a singular entry with the selected ids concatenated together. 
I'm guessing I need to create a custom save method for the second model, but I can't figure it out.

models.py

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    account_id = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    email_address = models.EmailField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey("app.ModelA")
    zip_codes = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

forms.py

```
class ModelBForm(forms.ModelForm):

    zip_codes = forms.CharField(widget=forms.SelectMultiple())

    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        exclude = ("a",)
```

upon saving a form submission, the table for ModelB will have data like this

```
a_id | zip_codes
1    | [90210, 53075, 23703]
```

Ideally, I would want something like this

```
a_id | zip_codes
1    | 90210
1    | 53075
1    | 23703
```

Comment: If I understand your problem you are looking for [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#post-save).

Comment: What do you mean by _a singular entity with the selected ids concatenated together_? Can you post your models?

Comment: Updated w my models and more information

Comment: You should probably use a (inline) formset to begin with. Then you can create multiple B instances with one zip each without much hassle.